# Sequence with positive items

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Consider the $a_n$ sequence, where $n\geq 2, a_2=a_3=1$, and if $k\geq 3$, then $$(k+1)(k-2)a_{k+1}=k(k^2-k-1)a_k-(k-1)^3a_{k-1}.$$

Prove that if $a_m$ is a positive integer, then $m$ is a prime number!

Comment: I was perhaps too rushing with answering the question, forgot to point out to add some context to the question. Can you add information about what have you tried? And also what is source of this problem? Suggesting to do this for any future asked question as well, since this site is not primarily for solving problems, and if a person who asks the question does not show any effort, the question gets usually downvoted or even closed quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

For $\;m=4=3+1\;$ :

$$(3+1)(3-2)a_4=3(3^2-3-1)a_3-(3-1)^3a_2\iff4a_4=15-8\implies a_4=\frac74>0$$

yet $\;4\;$ isn't prime.

Did I miss something...?

Comment: No, I missed something. Now it is correct, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the first few values of the sequence, you notice
$$1,1,7/4,5,121/6,103,5041/8,40321/9,\dots$$ 
Looking at the nominators themselves we have a sequence (after possible normalizing denominator to form rising sequence) 
$$2,3,7,25,121,\dots$$

You can either guess or check on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C25%2C121%2C721&language=english&go=Search). The sequence of nominators looks just like $k!+1$ (shifted), so we conjecture that $a_k = ((k-1)!+1)/k$. To prove this is actually the case, you can use induction, it is quite straightforward.

Now the primality result follows from [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) directly, since $a_k$ being an integer is equivalent to $(k-1)!+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{k}$.